# How to improve query performance when applying multiple filters?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a ternary relationship, called `ternary` like this:

```
id_Offer    -   id_Profile  -   id_Skill
1           -   1           -   1
1           -   2           -   1

[and so on, there would be more registers for each id_Offer from Offer but I want to limit the example]
```

The table Profile looks something like this (profile_interest is a table that stablish the relationship between profile and interest, that's all):

```
id_Profile -   profile_name
1          -   profile-1
2          -   profile-2
3          -   profile-3
```

So when I make the following query, the more OR clauses I add the worse the query performs, starting at ~0.1-0.2 seconds, which is the what I get for any other query I make, and up to 1.5 seconds.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ternary_table.id_profile, COUNT(distinct profile_interest.id_interest) as matching 
FROM ternary_table INNER JOIN profile ON ternary_table.id_profile=profile.id_profile 
INNER JOIN profile_interest ON profile.id_profile=profile_interest.id_profile 
WHERE profile_interest.id_interest= '1' 
 OR profile_interest.id_interest = '2' 
 OR profile_interest.id_interest = '3'
 OR profile_interest.id_interest = '14'
 OR profile_interest.id_interest = '15'
 OR profile_interest.id_interest = '16'
GROUP BY(ternary_table.id_profile) 
ORDER BY matching DESC;
```

I have tried making the field profile_interest.id_interest an indexed column with:

`CREATE INDEX filter_interest ON profile_interest(id_interest );`

With no improvement whatsoever. The database weighs less than a Gigabyte, is a very small database with ~15 tables, so I would like to know if there is any way to shorten the query lag.

Edit: To add more information, the reason I am worried about this is because the only purpose of this data is to connect to an API so any delay in the SQL will delay every call to this data.

Edit1: Added EXPLAIN output and removed first distinct since it's unnecessary

```
+----+-------------+---------------------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------------+------------+---------+------------------------------------+------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table               | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                  | key        | key_len | ref                                | rows | filtered | Extra                                                     |
+----+-------------+---------------------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------------+------------+---------+------------------------------------+------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | profile_interest      | NULL       | range  | PRIMARY,id_interest,filter_interest | id_interest | 202 | NULL                               |   40 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | perfil              | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                        | PRIMARY    | 202     | BBDD.profile_interest.id_perfil    |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                               |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | oferta_skill_perfil | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY,id_skill,id_perfil                     | id_perfil  | 202     | BBDD.profile_interest.id_perfil    | 4609 |   100.00 | Using index                                               |
+----+-------------+---------------------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------------+------------+---------+------------------------------------+------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Edit 2: Added table creation per request

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

CREATE TABLE profile (
    id_profile VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    name_profile VARCHAR(200),
    type_profile VARCHAR(200),
    PRIMARY KEY (id_profile)
);


CREATE TABLE ternary (
    id_oferta VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    id_skill VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    id_profile VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    ranking_skill DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_oferta, id_skill, id_profile),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_oferta) REFERENCES oferta(id_oferta),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_skill) REFERENCES skill(id_skill),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_profile) REFERENCES profile(id_profile)
);

 CREATE TABLE interest (
    id_interest VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    name_interes VARCHAR(200),
    PRIMARY KEY (id_interest)
 );


CREATE TABLE profile_interest (
    id_profile VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    id_interest VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id_profile, id_interest),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_profile) REFERENCES profile(id_profile),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_interest) REFERENCES interes(id_interest)
);
```

Comment: maybe try inserting everything into a temp table, then query select * from my_temp_table where conditions

Comment: When you look at the explain plan, does the index actually get used? Also, just a syntax thing - use IN ('1','2', ...,'16') rather than sequential OR's.

Comment: The first DISTINCT is redundant.

Comment: Your `or`ed conditions can be simplified to `profile_interest.id_interest in ('1' , '2', ...)` (this should not change performance), The first `distinct` can be removed because the `group by` is already returning unique rows.  The `count(distinct)` can probably be replaced by a simple `count`

Comment: @Error_2646 I have tried looking the EXPLAIN output since it is often recommended but I am not going to lie, I do not make a lot of sense out of it, I will edit main post with its outcome in case someone else can see more than I do

Comment: avoid using "or" in the "where" clause

Comment: Any tips as to why @DenisJr ? I am quite new to this, just learned about how to use the IN syntax

Comment: Why do you have Primary Keys with exactly the same data type as the other columns? `VARCHAR(200)` for storing numeric data is bad and the joins probably need more resources.

Comment: @user20929302 - You are unlikely to be any faster with a manually generated temp table, than to let MySQL do its own thing.

Comment: @monkeyintern - No fair!  The indexes for `profile_interest` are different in the `EXPLAIN` than in the `CREATE TABLE` !

Comment: @DenisJr - This type of `OR` is equivalent to `IN`, so it is not as bad as other types of `OR`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try writing this as:

```
select tt.id_profile,
       (select count(distinct pi.id_interest)
        from profile_interest pi
        where tt.id_profile = pi.id_profile and
              pi.id_interest in (1, 2, 3, 14, 15, 16)
       ) as matching
from ternary_table tt;
```

For this to work, you need an index on `profile_interest(id_profile, id_interest)`.

EDIT:

If you only want rows that match, then you can add:

```
having matching > 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!! That is very interesting since it is returning me every result with a 0 (the original query did not do that, I don't even know how to do that!) but the really important thing is that if I add a GROUP BY it takes 0.00 seconds!! How would I go about not taking into account results where matching equals 0? Basically I do not understand why originally they were ommited and now they show up, on a theorical level.

Comment: @monkeyintern . . . If it is returning `0`, then check in the `in` list and the correlation condition.

Comment: @monkeyintern: A *Correlated Scalar Subquery* always returns a row (even if no rows with those interest_ids exist) and in your case zero due to the COUNT.

Comment: I am learning more SQL today than ever before. @dnoeth Since that correlated scalar subquery is done for a column returned, and not in a WHERE clause for example, how would I only get results above 0? What does the syntax look like for this CSS?

Comment: @monkeyintern: Well, you could use the CSS in the WHERE-clause, but to get value in the Select list *and* filter for `>0` you need to nest the Select in a *Derived Table*: `select * from (select tt.id_profile,... from ternary_table tt) as dt where matching > 0`

Comment: @monkeyintern - If Gordon's query does not give the right results, it should not be the approved answer.  You can move the checkmark to another Answer.  (Unless he fixes it.)

Comment: It gives such a great performance, and with only a few modifications and @dnoeth added help I got exactly what I wanted. I thought about editing the answer to add the full query once completed but I was unsure about if it was the best way to proceed

Comment: @monkeyintern . . . The best way to proceed is to edit the answer so it is correct -- for a minor edit.  If the question merely inspired an approach, you can also answer the question yourself.  If the issue is just filtering, then the modification is pretty trivial.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  id_profile,
        COUNT(id_interest) as matching
    FROM  profile_interest AS pi
    WHERE  id_interest IN (1,2,4,14,15,16)
      AND EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM oferta_skill_perfil
                                          WHERE id_profile = pi.id_profile )
      AND EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM profile  WHERE id_profile = pi.id_profile )
    GROUP BY id_profile
    ORDER BY  matching DESC;
```

And `profile_interest` needs `INDEX(id_interest, id_profile)` in this order.

I used `EXISTS` only because that seems to be the real purpose in touching the other tables.  But perhaps they don't need to be touched?

The slowdown is caused by what I call "Explode-Implode" or "inflate-deflate".  This happens when you `JOIN` some tables (which leads to more intermediate rows), then `GROUP BY` deflate back to what you started with. 
 The technique for getting rid of it is to *first* focus on doing the aggregates (`COUNT`, in your case), *then* `JOIN` as needed.

`EXISTs` is much faster when you just need to check for the existence, not actually find all 4609 rows.

`profile_interest` seems to be a many-to-many mapping table.  See my tips [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table).

Note that it recommends the index I suggest above.

Normally ids are integers; why do you have `VARCHAR(200)`?  There is no obvious source of such long strings.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer. Too long for a comment...

FWIW, I find this easier to read...

```
SELECT x.id_profile
     , COUNT(DISTINCT i.id_interest) matching 
  FROM ternary_table x
  JOIN profile p 
    ON p.id_profile = x.id_profile
  JOIN profile_interest i
    ON i.id_profile = p.id_profile
 WHERE i.id_interest IN(1,2,3,14,15,16)
 GROUP 
    BY x.id_profile
 ORDER 
    BY matching DESC;
```

Now, if only we could see SHOW CREATE TABLE statements as well as the EXPLAIN for that.

Comment: Just added EXPLAIN output, I will look into editing the Create Tables so as to not leak anything relevant

Comment: Just added the Create tables. And just now realized there is a command that you meant to use THE command. I hope it's enough since it's pretty much the same info :/

Comment: @monkeyintern It's not the same, because you appear to add indexes after creating the tables. We need to see the tables as they appeared when the query was executed.

Answer (score 0):

Your query can probably be reduced to:

```
SELECT id_profile, 
   COUNT(distinct id_interest) as matching  -- or COUNT(*)??
FROM profile_interest 
WHERE id_interest IN(1,2,3,14,15,16) -- those ids are probably integers, not strings
GROUP BY id_profile
ORDER BY matching DESC;
```

Comment: I still need the INNER JOIN because of what I am required to return (which are columns of two different tables in this case), and I did'nt know about the IN syntax so that's something I've already learned, thanks for the answer! Do not know why the IDs work both with \' and without the quotes, but yeah, they are IDs, weird for me that both work

Comment: When you compare a string to a numeric value the string is automatically (in some DBMSes) casted to a numeric value. You can use the result of this Select as a *Derived Table* to join to additional tables.